# Is there a way to vectorize this code piece in matlab / octave?

Tags: matlab, octave, vectorization

Is there a way to vectorize this code piece?

```
for k=1:K
    vec_y(:,k) = y == k;
end
```

Here, `y` is a vector of `3000x1` dimension, and has elements `1` through `10` (representations) such that each representation has equal count as every other representation (i.e., there will be `300` counts of `1`, `300` counts of `2`, etc.).

What I want to do is rewrite or just create a new matrix that has the following binary representation for all occurrences of corresponding `1`-`10`:

`1` will be represented by `[1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0]`, `2` will be `[0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0]`, and so on.

I want to fully vectorize the code without using `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** as suggested by @Suever

One possibility:

```
% Sample y values
y = [1;9;5;6;3]

% Resulting matrix
m = bsxfun(@eq, 1:10, y)

m =

     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: You don't actually need the `repmat` since you're using `bsxfun`. You can just write `bsxfun(@eq, 1:10, y)`

Comment: It works well. Thanks! Unfortunately I can't vote your answer since I don't have required reputation / points. :)

Comment: If you have R2016b, this becomes simply `y == (1:10)` via implicit expansion.